# Seagate External Drive works on PC but not mac, sometimes

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, hard-drive, external-hard-drive

I've having some trouble with my Seagate USB External hard drive. It's formatted FAT32 and I use it primarily on my Mac (OSX Mavericks)

Every now and then (it's happened twice now), It would stop recognizing on the mac, and a disk repair in disk utility would not help.

However, I noticed it did work under windows. I performed some reads and some write to the disk by moving files around, and then voila, it worked on OSX again.

Doing the usual disk repair gives the error `Error: Disk Utility can’t repair this disk. Back up as many of your files as possible, reformat the disk, and restore your backed-up files.`

Yet, the drive works fine under Windows 7 and appears to be fine under Linux/Mint. (Write operations sometimes fail).

The drive is formatted FAT32 with msdos filesystem. Is there anything I can do to fix this permanently? I don't have the space to fully back up the drive, its an almost full 1TB drive.

Comment: You have an almost full 1TB hard drive, with data you care about, that you're having this much trouble with, but that you're not backing up? That's…well…it's ridiculous. Your first order of business is to go get another big drive and back the failing drive up. What if I told you you could fix it by running some software that tweaks your partition table or your file allocation tables? Would you want to risk modifying low-level disk data structures when 1TB of data is on the line?